# Client viewing before deployment

Tags: customization

I'm currently building a site on my local computer. I will transfer the finished product onto my client's new host/domain. Before he chooses this, what's the best way for him to view my current progress?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Questions should really be specific to WordPress. Your question as stated isn't really a WP question, but is more of a general development/hosting question. It might be better posted to https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a lot of plugins where you can make all modifications on your theme, plugins and only logged users will see those changes, so you could show your client while for not logged in users will see "Maintenance" or "Soon" mode.

Also you can make a authentication log in system on your host "If that permit" to see your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using doing it on your device, the best way to share progress is by sharing the full page screenshot or by sharing screen using any software you want.

And it would be better to do the designing on production site, since you can stop others from seeing it using plugins.